# Update method not updating record in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i have create a scaffold controller in which i can delete a record, update a record and create a new record. All methods working fine but update method not working. When i update any record then on submit it just show me flash notice that record updated successful but when i check my db nothing was change. Here below my update method in my controller.Kindly suggesst me what i have done wrong please.

```
    def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @member = Member.find(params[:id])
        format.html { redirect_to @member, notice: 'Member was successfully updated.' }
        format.js { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @member.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 7):

It's because you didn't tell it to update. You should have:

```
@member = Member.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @member.update(member_params) # of course, you should have `member_params` method defined properly
  # the rest of your code
```

Comment: Also remember to permit each model attribute you wish to update.

Comment: Of course, this should be in `member_params` method.

Comment: Try using `update` in place of `update_attributes`, as `update_attributes` has been deprecated in rails 4

Comment: @RSB what do you mean by that? Usage of `update_attributes` doesn't even show deprecation warning.